# Convergence of a probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_{n,b}, n,b \in \mathbb{N}$ be a double-indexed nonnegative real random variable with 
\begin{align} 
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} X_{n,b} = c >0 \qquad \text{a.s.}
\end{align}
How can I show in a mathematically rigorous way that we have 
\begin{align} 
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}( X_{n,b}>0)=1?
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that I additionally know that $ \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} X_{n,b} = X_n $ almost surely for some random variables $X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then it follows trivially that I have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_{n,b}>0)&= 1-  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_{n,b} \leq 0) \\
&= 1-  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_{n} \leq 0) \\
&= 1-  \mathbb{P}(c \leq 0) = 1 \\
\end{align}
since almost sure convergence implies convergence in distribution. I would appreciate it if you could just vote on this to see if it's all right.